# Calculating short partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

We have $u(x,y) $ and $v(x,y)$ satisfying $x=uv$ , $ y=1/u$.  I got

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = y  ,  
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = x
\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 1-y  ,  
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -1/y^2
\end{equation}

Are these correct?

Comment: Surely you notice that $u=1/y$, $v=xy$.

Comment: I accidentally switched up u and v, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u=\frac1y$ and $v=xy$ thus
$$u_x=0 \quad u_y=-\frac1{y^2}$$

$$v_x=y \quad v_y=x$$